# Using Reflection EWS API C#

Tags: c#, api, dll, reflection, exchangewebservices

I'am trying to using EWS API in SSIS Script Task, but, the server doens't have the correspond dll: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

So, the reflection is the only solution i found, the file of dll it's in the server and i can use.

I need to instantiate a subclass of an abstract class, but the compiler give this message error: Not found the constructor of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo

I tried to use Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter.IsEqualTo and get nested type of SearchFilter, and none works

```
   Type typeSearchFilter = DLL2.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter");


    var typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo = typeSearchFilter.GetNestedType("IsEqualTo");

    Type typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo0 = DLL2.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo");

    Type typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo1 = DLL2.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter.IsEqualTo");

    dynamic searcherFilter = Activator.CreateInstance(typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo, new object[] { folderSchemaDisplayName, folder})
```

I expected create a new instance of SearchFilter.IsEqualTo and pass the parameters to constructor and save the result in variable, like this

```
          dynamic searcherFilter = Activator.CreateInstance(typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo, new object[] { folderSchemaDisplayName, folder});

            var filter = searcherFilter;
```

Comment: Consider telling us the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than showing us your broken solution.  Read [What is the X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm trying to create an instance of SearchFilter.IsEqualTo with parameters, but, isn't recognized the constructor of SearchFilter.IsEqualTo, compiler says that not found a constructor, in none of the cases attempted

Comment: How hard would it be to just put the necessary DLL on the server?

Comment: The DLL is on server, but not in GAC, i'm trying with other area to put the DLL on server, but my company is the biggest on Brazil and everything is so complicated. With DLL referenced on Windows works fine, but I need to make works in two ways, if not get by dll on server in gac

Comment: Hmm, not sure why you need it in GAC.  Is it so that it runs in full trust?

Comment: To use in SSIS Script Task, I reference local in my machine and the C# change the path to gac dll windows. So, when deploy to server, if is registered in gac I can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your "typeSearchFilterIsEqualTo" parameter must be a reference to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema.DisplayName, it is a public static field that is also in the DLL.

Here is a full example:

```
var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll");

var isEqualsTo = DLL.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo");

var param1 = DLL.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema").GetField("DisplayName").GetValue(null);
var param2 = "C:\\";

var instance1 = Activator.CreateInstance(isEqualsTo, new[] { param1, param2 });

// or...

var typeParam1 = DLL.GetType("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyDefinitionBase");
var typeParam2 = typeof(object);

var ctor = isEqualsTo.GetConstructor(new[] { typeParam1, typeParam2 });

var instance2 = ctor.Invoke(new[] { param1, param2 });
```